# How to take backup of nginx cache folder along with metadata?

Tags: nginx

I want to take a backup of nginx cache folder ( the `proxy_cache_path` ) and its metadata of the main server and use that as the cache folder of a secondary server. This is so that if the main server goes down the secondary server can take its place and serve the cached urls.

Is it possible to do this ?

I know where the cached files are located and I can copy them, but I think its useless without the metadata associated with it.

Help please ?

Comment: Use a shared filesystem (e.g. NFS served from your SAN storage) to store the cache.

Comment: What is the point to cache meta data and particularly open file descriptors? This is the file system problem, not Nginx.